# Disable Boot Flash completely on ATMega

Tags: bootloader

I want to reclaim the space reserved for the bootloader on my ATMega32u4 (Leonardo chip).
But the lowest boot flash size I can see is BOOTSZ=11 which is 256 words (512 bytes). Is it not possible to completely disable it?
Basing this off of this: http://www.engbedded.com/fusecalc

Answer (score 4):

It is not possible to set the bootloader space to 0, but it is possible to unlock the bootloader space entirely by unprogramming the lock bits as well as to enable normal booting by unprogramming BOOTRST in the high fuse byte. Access to the entire chip will then be fully unrestricted.